# How to display the geometry type of features in the attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Does anybody know how to display the geoemtry type of features in the attribute table?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use field calculator with function `geom_to_wkt` which gives you WKT representation (geometry type, coordinates). Then add some string handling for gain only geometry type:

```
left(geom_to_wkt($geometry),strpos(geom_to_wkt($geometry),' ')-1)
```

`strpos` takes position of first space (`' '`) character in whole WKT string and print this number (-1 for removing extra space) of characters from the left. The result will be geometry type (`Polygon`, `MultiPolygon` etc.).

[image]

If you need to keep this attribute updated, check *Create virtual field*. How  virtual fields work is described in [Editing attribute values](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-attribute-values) in QGIS documentation.